# CGWindowListCreateImage yields blurred cgImage when zoomed

Tags: macos, core-graphics, retina-display, nswindow, zooming

I'm developing a magnifying glass like application for mac. My goal is to be able to pinpoint individual pixels when zoomed in. I'm using this code in mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent):

```
let captureSize = self.frame.size.width / 9     //9 is the scale factor
 let screenFrame = (NSScreen.main()?.frame)!
 let x = floor(point.x) - floor(captureSize / 2)
    let y = screenFrame.size.height - floor(point.y) - floor(captureSize / 2)

    let windowID = CGWindowID(self.windowNumber)

cgImageExample = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: captureSize, 
height: captureSize), CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenBelowWindow, windowID, 
CGWindowImageOption.bestResolution)
```

The creation of the cgImage takes place in the CGWindowListCreateImage method. When I later draw this in an NSView, the result looks like this:

[image]

It looks blurred / like some anti-aliasing was applied during the creation of the cgImage. My goal is to get a razor sharp representation of each pixel. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It was a matter of setting the interpolation quality to none on the drawing context:

```
 context.interpolationQuality = .none
```

Result:

[image]

On request some more code:

```
//get the context
guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current()?.cgContext else { return }

//get the CGImage
let image: CGImage = //pass the result from CGWindowListCreateImage call

//draw
context.draw(image, in: (CGRect of choice))
```

Comment: Dear @Tuslareb, would you please be so kind and provide an example of the `context`? I’m facing the same issue. I also generate a screenshot using `CGWindowListCreateImage` but the resulting CGImage is blurred when zoomed. I basically convert the screenshot to a `NSImage` and then display it within an ImageView.

Comment: @ixany I updated my answer with some example code. Basically, I draw the CGImage I get from the CGWindowListCreateImage call in the drawRect method of a custom NSView. Which CGWindowImageOption do you use in the  CGWindowListCreateImage call?